# What really are the units of enthalpy change?

Tags: enthalpy, units

A reasonable definition of *standard enthalpy change of formation* would be:

'The enthalpy change when one mole of a compound is formed from its constituent elements under standard conditions'

Enthalpy change itself is understood as 'the exchange of *energy* between a chemical reaction and its surroundings at constant pressure.'

I am a little confused on what the units of enthalpy change should be. For example, for the enthalpy change of formation of water, this is shown: ΔHf<sup>o</sup> = -285.8 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>

Now, if enthalpy change already contains 'one mole of a compound' in its definition, do we really need to include the per mole (mol<sup>-1</sup>) part in the enthalpy change? If enthalpy change is the change in just *energy*, how are the units kJ mol<sup>-1</sup> and not just kJ ? I am sorry if I am overthinking here.

Comment: You grab a shovelful of your compound, it reacts and gives you some kJ, you measure those and write the number down for later use. Next time you have a whole dump truck of the same compound. Will the number of kJ be the same?

Comment: I agree with your logic, but enthalpy change of formation itself describes me taking only a mole in my shovelful of compound (as far as I know).